# How can I make a div scroll horizontally and also have elements inside it float left?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, pug, styling

I have a div with class `.media-record-container` which contains a bunch of divs with class `.media-record`. I want the container div to scroll horizontally if more records are added than can fit. I achieved this by adding `display: inline-block` to `.media-record` and `overflow: auto` to `.media-record-container`. Now here's my problem. I want the `.media-records` to all float left instead of centering but if I add `float:left`, it forces the `.media-record-container` div to scroll vertically instead of horizontally. What can I do to accomplish both horizontal scroll and float left together?

**CSS**

```
.media-record-container {
  margin-left: 75px;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.media-record {
  height: 60px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #8e99a3;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 0%;
  white-space: normal !important;
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

**Jade**

```
.content-wrap.media-record-container.droppableRecord
  .offair.state.content-box.darker-font-color
    article.media-record(ng-repeat="record in mediaRecords")
      p.max-lines(style="white-space:normal") {{record.name}}
      h6.pull-right(ng-click="remove(record)") &times;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign

```
.media-record-container {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and you're done:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVMGVj

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
.media-record-container {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```